# HTTP Error 404 The requested resource is not available, Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish

when ever I press the submit action button to send the information to a controller i always get "HTTP 404 Status - not found: The requested resource is not available" I was just wondering if any could help me sort out this frustrating problem. Here is my Code:

LibraryInfo.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Library Information</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/bookServlet" method="POST">
    <fieldset style="width:300px">
    <legend>Find Book</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>ISBN Number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="isbn" required="required"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Find Book"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Book.java:

```
package com.farmani.model;

public class Book {
    private int isbn;
    private String author; 
    private String title; 
    private String status;
    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    } 

}
```

ConnectionClass.java

```
package com.farmani.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class ConnectionClass {
    private DataSource dataSource; 
    public ConnectionClass(){
        try{
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext(); 
            dataSource = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/employee"); 
        }catch(NamingException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conn = null; 
        try{
            conn=dataSource.getConnection(); 
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        return conn; 
    }
}
```

LibraryDAO.java

```
package com.farmani.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.farmani.model.Book;

public class LibraryDAO {
    private Connection connection; 
    public LibraryDAO(){
        ConnectionClass conn = new ConnectionClass(); 
        connection = conn.getConnection(); 
    }
    public Book getBookByISBN(int isbn){
        Book bk = new Book(); 
        try{
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from book where ISBN=?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1,isbn);
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); 
            if(rs.next()){
                bk.setIsbn(rs.getInt("ISBN"));
                bk.setAuthor(rs.getString("author"));
                bk.setTitle(rs.getString("title")); 
                bk.setStatus(rs.getString("status")); 
            }
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bk;
    }

}
```

bookServlet.java:

```
package com.farmani.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.farmani.dao.LibraryDAO;
import com.farmani.model.Book;


@WebServlet("/bookServlet")
public class bookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String BOOK_DETAILS="/LibraryDetails"; 
    private LibraryDAO dao; 


    public bookServlet() {
        super();
        dao = new LibraryDAO(); 
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int isbn = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("isbn")); 
        Book bk = dao.getBookByISBN(isbn); 
        request.setAttribute("Book",bk); 
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(BOOK_DETAILS); 
        view.forward(request,response); 
    }

}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>LibraryWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LibraryInfo.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

LibraryDetails.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Book Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<CENTER><h1><b>Book Details</b></h1></CENTER>
<ul>
<li>ISBN: ${Book.isbn}</li>
<li>Author: ${Book.author}</li>
<li>Title: ${Book.title }</li>
<li>Status: ${Book.status}</li> 
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you try this form tag: `<form action="bookServlet" method="POST">` ?  Also, please try adding a `doGet()` method to the `bookServlet` class and access the URL directly from your web browser.

Comment: I have tried different paths in the action form including the one you have suggested. I also tried by adding doGet(....){ doPost(request,response)} ... no luck

Comment: What version of Java and Glassfish are you using?

Comment: Glassfish 4.0 JDK1.8.0_25

Comment: Change the access modifier of `doPost` from `protected` to `public` &/or  replace `action="/bookServlet"` with `action="bookServlet"`.

Comment: `protected` should not be a problem in the method signature.

Comment: Can you put the old school mappings into your `web.xml` just to see if that works?  If it does work, then we know for certain the problem lies with the annotation.  If it doesn't work, then the problem is something else.

Comment: <servlet>
    <servlet-name>bookServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.farmani.controllers</servlet-class>
  </servlet> ... No Luck

Comment: Try replacing `@WebServlet("/bookServlet")` with `@WebServlet(name = "bookServlet" , urlPatterns = { "/bookServlet" })` or `@WebServlet(value = "/bookServlet")` For more info on this look at [@WebServlet - Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html)

Comment: *Have u tried to run ur app on any other server ?* Bcoz everything is working fine in ur configuration. I have tried to run this configuration on JBoss & it's working. May be it's compatibility issue with Glassfish.

Comment: Only glassfish ..as it was part of the requirement.

Comment: Hey, I have similar problem, but I can't find the answers anywhere. Were you able to solve it? Would you mind telling how too? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Give a period just before bookServlet in the form action. Like below.

    action="./bookServlet"

Answer (score 1):

give your servlet url path exactly in the `<form>` tag

Comment: Have tried that as well.. LibraryWeb/bookServlet ...http://localhost:8080/LibraryWeb/bookServlet...All sorts of different variations..no luck either.

Comment: can you show me your web.xml config

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>LibraryWeb</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>LibraryInfo.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>

Comment: are you using struts framework?

Comment: No just regular  java EE

Comment: then where is your servlet mapping config in web.xml?

Comment: I am using @WebServlet("/bookServlet") instead.

Comment: @greenhorn You don't need a mapping in web.xml anymore, as this file is being phased out in Java 8.  The annotation should be sufficient for the mapping, but Rez88 is not having any luck getting it to work.